# How to define a non-static function for JSObjectRef and get 'this' in this member function?

Tags: javascriptcore

I found Javascriptcore provides JSClassDefinition to define static values and functions, but cannot find how to define non-static functions.

How to define member function for a js object?

and how to get 'this' pointer in the member function?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have got the answer. We can use JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback:

```
JSStringRef funcName = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("memberFunction");
JSObjectRef funcObj = JSObjectMakeFunctionWithCallback(ctx, funcName, memberFunction);
JSObjectSetProperty(ctx, obj, funcName, funcObj, kJSPropertyAttributeNone, &exception);
JSStringRelease(funcName);
```

the `memberFunction` is:

```
JSValueRef memberFunction (JSContextRef ctx, JSObjectRef function, JSObjectRef thisObject, size_t argumentCount, const JSValueRef arguments[], JSValueRef* exception)
{
    OutputDebugStringA("MEMBER FUNCTION\n");
    return JSValueMakeNull(ctx);
}
```